# Significance of 8% character sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there something special about the character sequence of 8% in SQL Server?

I can't for the life of me figure out how the following query returns %H539 instead of %H5398%

```
DECLARE @contractnumber AS VARCHAR(5) = 'H5398'
if(@contractNumber is not null) set @contractNumber = '%' + @contractNumber + '%'
PRINT @contractnumber
```

Comment: This looks like you're getting ready to do a LIKE query with that value. LIKE queries with leading percent signs are notoriously inefficient, and can't be indexed. Depending on your data, you might want to read up on full text indices instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have a varchar(5). `'%H539'` is 5 characters... the field is full, and so the `'8%'` is truncated. Try a varchar(7) instead.

Comment: Better yet, a varchar(8000) and not worry about it. It will still take 7 bytes.

Comment: Thanks.  Always the simple things you overlook.